# Mysql UDF to return record id if exists else insert and return recordid`

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a Mysql Function to return a contactID if the record exists based on the parameters supplied, If the record is not present, I am adding the record and then returning the contactID of the new record.
But the function is throwing 1048error, Can you check and correct me if I went wrong in writing this.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `GetContactID`(accountNumber CHAR(45),UserID INT(11)) RETURNS char(1) CHARSET latin1
 DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
 DECLARE ContactID INT DEFAULT 0;
 SELECT ContactID INTO @ContactID FROM Contact WHERE AccountNumber = @accountNumber AND UserID = @UserID AND Status =1;
 IF ContactID = 0 or ContactID is null THEN
    INSERT INTO Contact(AccountNumber,UserID) VALUES (@accountNumber,@UserID);
    SELECT ContactID INTO @ContactID FROM Contact WHERE AccountNumber = @accountNumber AND UserID = @UserID;
 END IF;   
 RETURN  ContactID;
END
```

Can someone help me where I went wrong.
Thanks

Comment: Why `RETURNS char(1)`? That can't hold a `ContactID`.

Comment: `IF ContactID` should be `IF @ContactID`, shouldn't it?

Comment: You set a delimiter and then never use it?

Comment: @DigitalChris I guess it's on the next line after the code he showed.

Comment: Changed retun type to int from char. I am calling the function as select GetContactID('123',1), I am getting response as Error Code: 1048 Column 'UserID' cannot be null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem results from mixing user variables, local variables and parameters.

`@UserId` is not the same as `UserId` - they are different variables.
`UserId` is also a name of column in the table.

- **User defined variables** are wirtten as `@var_name`, are stored in the user session and can be used to pass values between differend stored routines that reference them, see this link for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html
- **local variables** are declared in stored routines using `DECLARE` keyword, their scope is local within the stored routine, see this link for details: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare-local-variable.html
- **Parameters of function/procedure** - they are declared in the procedure/function declaration, they are used to pass parameters to the stored routine from the caller, can be also used to return results from the routine to the caller (if declared as OUT or INOUT). Their scope is similar to local variables. For details see this link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Try this code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `GetContactID`(p_accountNumber CHAR(45),p_UserID INT(11)) RETURNS char(1) CHARSET latin1
         DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
   DECLARE v_ContactID INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT ContactID INTO v_ContactID 
   FROM Contact 
   WHERE AccountNumber = p_accountNumber AND UserID = p_UserID AND Status =1;
   IF v_ContactID = 0 or v_ContactID is null THEN
        INSERT INTO Contact(AccountNumber,UserID) 
            VALUES (p_accountNumber,p_UserID);
        SELECT ContactID INTO v_ContactID FROM Contact 
            WHERE AccountNumber = p_accountNumber AND UserID = p_UserID;
   END IF;   
   RETURN  v_ContactID;
END;
```

Notice that:

- function parameters are declared with prefix `p_`
- local variables are declared with prefix `v_`
- the function doesn't use any user variables (prefixed by @)

These prefixes help to avoid ambiguity - we know that `p_UserID` is a parameter, `v_UserId` is a local variable, and `UserID` is a column name in the table (If we would use `@UserId`, we knew that this was the user variable).

Comment: Thanks it worked, is there a way to return the ContactID without using select query. It is the primary key of Contact table.